# ¿Por qué se ejecuta el ELSE aunque la condición sea cierta? [Python]

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles, else

En el bloque IF ELSE de este fragmento de código se ejecuta el ELSE aun siendo el IF verdadero.

Cabe decir que el valor proviene de una función en otro archivo que retorna deliberadamente el valor 0, si lo declaro en una variable dentro del código principal si funciona.

A continuación os dejo el código de prueba:

```
from archivoop import saludar

nombre = input("Nombre: ")
print(saludar(nombre))
if saludar == 0:
    print("dentro print ", saludar)

else:
    print("error", saludar)
```

Y a continuacion la funcion que retorna 0:

```
def saludar(nombre):
    print("funcion: hola " + nombre)
    return 0
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Intenta con `if saludar(nombre) == 0`

Comment: Y dónde estás declarando el valor de `saludar`? Repasa un poco la sintaxis de python, en concreto la declaración de variables y el retorno de valores en las funciones... porque lo único que estás haciendo con el valor devuelto por tu método es imprimirlo! Además, lo único que has importado es la función `saludar`, y obviamente al ser una función no es nunca igual a 0! Necesitas usar una variable o comprobar con el valor devuelto de la llamada directamente como te indica @HeytalePazguato.

Comment: `saludar` se interpreta como nombre de función, y por tanto nunca será igual a cero.

Comment: Bien! al final he optado por probar la opción de Heytale directamente sobre el if y funciona.
También probé a asignar lo que devuelve la función a un valor y el valor compararlo en el IF y también funciona. 
Por tanto, mi error estaba en la forma de llamar a la función y/o en no haber declarado un variable con el valor de esa función.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda y disculpad, pero ya veis que voy aprendiendo cuando tengo algo de tiempo y despacio.